# Meaning of colon before text in orgmode

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting

I was working with orgmode when I typed colon follwed by a space and text.

```
: text
```

and the whole line got highlighted in blue (in my theme).
What does this mean in Org mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that it is a short "Example"

[Example](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that. What are the implications of example text? Are they not affected by any of the faces when exporting?

Comment: The colon prevents Org mode from interpreting whatever follows as an Org mode construct: e.g. `: * foo` is *not*  interpreted as a headline. It is just a string with no special properties.

Comment: so it's like a comment? in my org the colon space makes the following text gray, which is nice.